# Вытащить данные из справочника в табличную часть документа

Tags: 1с

Есть справочник Номенклатура, где хранится Наименование номенклатуры и ее СрокГодности в днях (30дн, 60дн и т.д.)

Есть документ РасходнаяНакладная с табличной частью ТабличнаяЧасть1, он заполняется на основании документа Заказ. В заказе нет СрокаГодности и это поле не заполняется.

Нужно из Номенклатуры по Наименованию вынести СрокГодности и записать это в ТЧ документа РасходжнаяНакладная

Answer (score 1):

Вам срок годности нужно заполнять не в момент изменения номенклатуры, а в момент когда на основании заказа создается реализация.

Поэтому, нужно доработать алгоритм создания на основании (см. ОбработкаЗаполнения) и доработать заполнения табличной части реализации.

Это нужно для того, чтобы у Вас сроки годности были заполнены сразу, за 1 запрос, а не как вы предлагаете кодом (каждую позицию нужно будет перевыбрать, чтобы срок годности отобразился).

Answer (score -1):

Решил сам свою проблему. Решение ниже, мб кому поможет.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ТабличнаяЧасть1НоменклатураПриИзменении(Элемент)

строка=Элементы.ТабличнаяЧасть1.ТекущиеДанные; 
строка.СрокГодности=ПолучитьСрокГодности(строка.Номенклатура);


КонецПроцедуры

&НаСервереБезКонтекста
Функция ПолучитьСрокГодности(Номенклатура)

   Возврат Номенклатура.СрокГодности; 

КонецФункции
```